# How to add to zf2 navigation someting like OnClick="a();" to do action without controller?

Tags: javascript, navigation, zend-framework2

I have navigation building from array config, and can i add some parameter to do JS?

Comment: Or how i can change my translation locale without redirecting or using action in cntroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just make the redirect

```
`return $this->redirect()->toUrl($this->request->getServer('HTTP_REFERER'));`
```

in my action that change my locale.